# How to make rounded corner thumbnail " containing image of the post "?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, vector, designers, website-templates

When I create rounded rectangles in Photoshop, I can mask images over those rounded rectangles to give them rounded corners.

When I'm making websites however, I'm not sure how to give images rounded corners.

I don't know how to use vector masks on website, do you think it's the right solution? 
Please, if anyone can provide me with a tutorial or anything I will be very thankful.

Online example:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This effect is made with CSS.

Simply add a `border-radius` attribute to your image to make it have rounded corners.

Example:

```
img {
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

(That would apply it to all images)

Here is a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/XUUjz/2/) you can play around with.

Comment: So in the psd file when i design the interface i should not put any thing in my considerations , because i want the tumbnails to be rounded rectangle !!

Comment: When designing the interface in Photoshop, just use what you're used to (use masks to do rounded images), but then when you implement that design to a webpage, use the CSS attribute.

Comment: This answer is spot on but however let me tell you one more thing, you can not achieve rounded corners easily in css for **IE** all other modern browser will act accordingly but IE will need more efforts.

Comment: Johannes : Thank you , what i do is select " Rectangle tool " > Create shape > select rounded rectangle > Subtract (-) the rounded rectangle shape from the rectangle shape 

Simply the rectangle box is subtracted by Rounded rectangle box and then i put the image under this layer so it looks with rounded corners. 
this the only way i know ... the problem i have to resize the pictures so they dont appear on the sides  

please see this image http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/6223/webdesign2s.jpg 

is this good way for CSS or there is a better way , if you dont mind please send me a tutorial.

Comment: is there any problem how i make it ? or it doesnt matter because its all in CSS hands not photoshop ones? 
whats the optimum way to make it if yes or no ?

Comment: For that, I think it would get a bit more complicated and you'd need to use Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use timthumb so you dont have to worry about exact image sizes for your rectangles, and then use Johannes tip above for the rounded corners.

http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/

Answer (score 0):

I realize your question is really pertaining to CSS3 border-radius, but I thought I would drop this link to [PolyClip](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/10/29/clipping-jpeg-images-into-non-rectangular-polygons-using-polyclip-js/), which allows you to create vector masks in a web browser. Makes it so you can use a much small JPG file and a clipping path instead of a large PNG file with alpha transparency. So if you're looking to clip images more complex than rounded corner boxes, this would be the route to go.

Comment: Hey JamEs , the problem i am not a css expert , all what i need to do is just to handle a photoshop psd files to developer as i am outsourcing person and good with photoshop 

So i dont know if the rounded corner frames should be done in the psd file or just show him its rounded corners and he do it with css !!

2- the user thumbnails is also rounded corners , when i saw for example twitter gui psd , i see him made it grey mask vector with rounded corners, which i dont know if i should do this,because i dont know how to make rounded corners frames that fit to css . i can just do it in general

Comment: Use the rounded corners in photoshop to show what you'd like your web person to recreate, then they can create the rounded corners using code. If you are coding the site and not familiar with how to output the code, I suggest something like http://border-radius.com/ that would allow you to create the box you want visually, then output the code for you to copy and paste into a stylesheet.